# How to get the hotkey definition if a shortcut is pressed?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, hotkeys, key-binding

For example, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in this order, how I do get the corresponding hotkey definition?

I expect something like the following:

```
; pseudo code
*::MsgBox %A_ThisHotkey% was pressed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking how to code the hotkey definition... see `Hotkey Modifier Symbols` under `Hotkeys` in Help. There may be an all-encompassing global hotkey trigger, but if it is, I don't know what it is.

Once you know the basic modifier syntax you won't need this though. Also, as it relates to modifiers, there isn't an "order"--they're either pressed or they're not when the hotkey triggers, and it doesn't really matter what order you pressed them in once you hit <kbd>c</kbd> in the example listed.

```
; ^ = Control
; + = Shift
; ! = Alt
```

So the hotkey definition is...

```
 ^+!c::
```

Also, it turns out there is a way to do something along the lines of what you were asking, although I have never tried it out or used it before.  See `GUI Control Types` in Help, and then `Hotkey` from the table of contents in `GUI Control Types`... this can create a special GUI control capable of capturing input and converting it to the hotkey definition...

```
Gui, Add, Hotkey, vChosenHotkey
Gui, Show

Loop {
    Gui, Submit, NoHide
    ToolTip % ChosenHotkey
    Sleep 10
}
```